# Cross Origin in ajax call using ASP.NET MVC

Tags: json, ajax, asp.net-mvc, cross-domain, jsonp

I am using Visual Studio Version 2013 having MVC framework 4.5.

I am calling the ActionResult using ajax like:

```
$.ajax({
                type: "POST",
                url: $("#hdnSiteUrl").val() + 'Home/UserLogin',
                data: JSON.stringify(dataJson),
                contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
                datatype: "jsonp",
                async: false,
                success: function (msg) {
                    if (msg == 'false') {
                        $("#loginerror").show();
                        $("#loginerror").text("UserName or Password is wrong.");
                    }
                    else {
                        //window.location.href = ($("#hdnSiteUrl").val());
                        window.location.reload();
                    }
                },
                error: function (msg) {
                }
            });
```

The problem I am facing right now is cross origin in some computer but in some computer it is running fine.

How do I solve this issue?

Please someone who has solved help me to solve this issue!

I have also tried to send the data using datatype: jsonp in some computer it is running but in some computer still have problem.

Answer (score 0):

JSONP stands for “JSON with Padding” and it is a workaround for loading data from different domains. It loads the script into the head of the DOM and thus you can access the information as if it were loaded on your own domain, thus by-passing the cross domain issue.

and you are using own mvc project url  `url: $("#hdnSiteUrl").val() + 'Home/UserLogin',`

try to change dataType:'jsonp' to

```
dataType: 'json',
```

for more clarify:

```
(function($) {
var url = 'http://www.jquery4u.com/scripts/jquery4u-sites.json?callback=?';

$.ajax({
type: 'GET',
url: url,
async: false,
jsonpCallback: 'jsonCallback',
contentType: "application/json",
dataType: 'jsonp',
success: function(json) {
   console.dir(json.sites);
},
error: function(e) {
   console.log(e.message);
}
});

})(jQuery);
```

You can also alow cross domain to allow calling data from different domain for that one following code need to in your web.config file

```
<system.webServer>
<httpProtocol>
<customHeaders>
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Origin" value="http://localhost" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Headers" value="X-AspNet-Version,X-Powered-By,Date,Server,Accept,Accept-Encoding,Accept-Language,Cache-Control,Connection,Content-Length,Content-Type,Host,Origin,Pragma,Referer,User-Agent" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Allow-Methods" value="GET, PUT, POST, DELETE, OPTIONS" />
  <add name="Access-Control-Max-Age" value="1000" />
</customHeaders>
```

Comment: I have already mentioned that I have used jsonp but still facing the same issue. and the config file you are telling to change is creating error of type 400 so what can I do now! Thanks in advance.

Comment: ok try to use "crossOrigin: true" check this [Url-link](http://www.ajax-cross-origin.com)